# Prove that $\ker f$ is an ideal of $R$ with $f:R\rightarrow S$ a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

First of all, I'm not english speaker, so I will try to explain myself as good as possible.

> I have to prove that $\ker f$ is an ideal of $R$ with $f:R \rightarrow S$ a ring homomorphism.

This means I have to prove:

- $\ker f$ is additive subgroup of $R$.
- $(\ker f) R + R \ker f$ is contained in $\ker f$, equivalently, $kr$, $r'k'$ belongs to $\ker f$ for $k,k' \in \ker f$, $r,r' \in R$.

I already proved that $\ker f$ is additive subgroup of $R$, but I can't figure how to prove the second part.

I hope you can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Assume $r \in \ker f$. So $f(r)=0$. Your goal is to deduce $f(kr)=0$. Working backward, you can rewrite $f(kr)$ using the homomorphism property... I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $k\in\ker f$ and $r\in R$, then $f(rk)=f(r)\times f(k)=f(r)\times0=0$ and therefore $kr\in\ker f$. By the same argument, $kr\in\ker f$.

Comment: One minor thing is you switch the order of multiplication at one point. Obviously the proof still works though.

Comment: @Gage I've edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I  did the same when trying to prove it, but when I did f(r) * f(k) I thought that f(k)=e' with e' the unit element, so that f(r) * f(k) = f(r) * e' = f(r)
That's because I thought the kerf was sending R elements to 1 instead to 0.

Comment: @puradrogasincortar If my answer was useful, please mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $0 \in$ $ker f$ because of $f(0) = 0$.

If $a,b \in$ $ker f$, then $f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b) = 0 + 0 = 0$, so $a+b \in$ $ker f$.

If $a \in$ $ker f$ and $r \in$ $R$, then $f(r*a) = f(r) * f(a) = 0 * f(a) = 0$, so $r*a \in$ $ker f$.